# Session Id Management in Servlets

Tags: java, servlets, session-management

I am having some issues with my web application while doing a performance test with Jmeter. My question is not around Jmeter instead, it's around a simple Servlet session management behavior.

So we have a web application, where in when you request a login page, it passes back a "Session Id" in response headers and that is used for subsequent request made by browser. Session Id is passed along with username and password and if authenticated a new session id is returned and session is maintained with that session id going ahead. 
This is using cookies.

Now in Jmeter we have a thread based approach for load testing. When I run threads parallely what is essentially happening is that each thread request a login page and somehow only the last thread to request login page is authenticated as I feel that subsequent login page that comes with a new session id in cookie, invalidates the old or other session ids.

This is inspite of the fact that each thread is a different session and has it's own cookie manager. It's quite wierd.

However my questions are:

1. Does it make sense to have session id coming with login page; I see that maybe session is created as soon as application is accessed, but is it that, what sets a new cookie with session id? This application was already written so I am just wondering.
2. If each thread's session id is being overriden in jmeter does that mean, that i am not able to allocate a seperate cookie manager properly? Also even if threads are different sessions is there a possibility, old session id or cookie would be discarded?

How would Server know to invalidate the session id/cookie for subsequent requests? I am sure, not basis of IP address of requestor, as different browsers would still let me open parallel multiple sessions.

Any ideas, clarifications and light on the issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Server will just timeout the session it definitely sounds like you are over writing cookies here.

Have you tried seeing how it manages by including session ids in the url (simulate cookies being disabled in the browser) Does this work?

Answer (score 0):

Has this been solved at all?
I would say that having a session id in the login page is quite unusual. Session are meant for storing data server side and associate that data to connected users. Of course, prior to authenticate the user, there shouldn't be any data server side.